# Finding Percentage between two columns python

Tags: python, pandas

I a have data set like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1" :["A","B","B","B","A"], "col_2": ["JK","ML","ML","JK","JK"]})
```

So I want to find percentage of these two columns. example I want to know percentage of `"JK" & "ML" in B`

right now Im doing through subsetting.

My method is something like:

```
df_B = df.loc[df['col_1']=='B']
df_B['col_2'].value_counts(normalize = True)*100
```

Is there any other method without doing the subset?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df['col_1'],df['col_2'],normalize ='index')
Out[180]: 
col_2        JK        ML
col_1                    
A      1.000000  0.000000
B      0.333333  0.666667
```